# Post JSON from jQuery to Rails 4 App and save as session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out how to send JSON via post from jQuery to a Rails app and save the JSON data as a session variable. Here is what I have so far:

**jQuery Code**

```
info = '{"data": {"color": "green"}}'

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/save-design',
  data: info,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    alert("OK");
  },
  error: function(){
  }
});
```

**Rails Controller Code**

```
def save_design
    data = json_params
    session[:check] = data
    head :no_content
end

private

def json_params
    params.require(:data).permit(:color)
end
```

**Server Error Log**

```
Started POST "/cart/save-design" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-03 12:52:37 -0700
Processing by CartsController#save_design as */*
Parameters: {"{\"data\": {\"color\": \"green\"}}"=>nil, "locale"=>"en"}
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=abc_development collection=sessions selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"Lroqq29V1QVt7ebIM5ENwFeN0FM"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.6210ms
Completed 400 Bad Request in 7ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: data):
app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:47:in `json_params'
app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:30:in `save_design'
```

It would seem the problem is with my strong params but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dataType: 'json'` to your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/save-design',
  data: info,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    alert("OK");
  },
  error: function(){
  }
});
```

And make sure `info` is a valid JavaScript object, not a plain String.

Comment: That works. Did not need dataType: 'json' but needed a valid object. I've seen an example that stringified a json object before posting and that was my issue. Thank you!!!